# Swift STOMP TLS

Tags: ios

Is this no longer available in STOMP Livebury? I wonder if I should get TLS certification

The server connection continues to receive authentication errors with 401

Is the only way to solve it is to get a certificate issued?

[self.socket = SRWebSocket(urlRequest: urlRequest! as URLRequest, protocols: [], allowsUntrustedSSLCertificates: true)]

[self.socket = SRWebSocket(urlRequest: urlRequest! as URLRequest, protocols: [], allowsUntrustedSSLCertificates: true)]